# Why is a label being truncated on device but is ok in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I've got a label in my storyboard which is being truncated when the app runs on a phone and I don't know why that is.

Above is as it appears in the storyboard
[image]

But this is what it looks like when the app is run:
[image]

I didn't change any properties of the label, just dragged and dropped it into place then dragged and stretched its length.

Comment: Have you used Autolayout?

Comment: Yes autolayout is ticked, I unticked it and now its ok

Comment: As I can see in screenShot you have posted,you also have autolayout constraints on label, If you can also tell the constraints that you have applied to label, I can help

Answer (score 0):

=> have you try with NSLineBreakByCharWrapping UIlabel

Comment: here is one link from where it might useful to:
https://gist.github.com/danielphillips/1005520

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the width constraint, the label only needs the leading and bottom constraint (in this case), and optionally a trailing constraint in case the text is too long.

Answer (score 0):

First thing If you have given fixed width constraint then remove it,because label has its intrinsic size i.e it determine its size from to its content,So you just need to add constraints for positioning of label i.e x position and y position. So just give these constraints, for example -

1. Leading Space Constraint from superView.
2. Top Space Constraint to from superView.